# For all $\varphi \in (\mathbb{R}^d)^*, |\varphi|=1$, $\limsup_{h \downarrow 0}\frac{|\varphi(B_{t,t+h})|}{\sqrt{h \ln\ln (1/h)}} \geq c$ a.s.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, probability-limit-theorems

Let $B$ be a $d$-dimensional standard Brownian motion. Fix $t \geq 0$. I have to show the following:

> There is a $c>0$ such that for all $\varphi \in (\mathbb{R}^d)^*$ with $|\varphi|=1$, $$ \mathbb{P}\left( \limsup_{h \downarrow 0}\frac{|\varphi(B_{t,t+h})|}{\sqrt{h \ln\ln (1/h)}} \geq c\right)=1$$

By the law of iterated logarithm one would expect to show this with $c=\sqrt{2}$, but all my efforts have been futile.

I tried to reason as follows: Since $|\varphi|=1$, there is a sequence in the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$, say $\{x_n\}$, such that $|\varphi(x_n)| \uparrow 1$ as $n \uparrow \infty$. Now, *if I could write $x_n = \frac{B_{t,t+h_n}}{|B_{t,t+h_n}|}$ for some sequence $h_n \downarrow 0$ and if (perhaps through a subsequence) $\frac{|B_{t,t+h_n}|}{\sqrt{h_n \ln\ln (1/h_n)} }\uparrow \sqrt{2}$ as $n \uparrow \infty$, I would have,*  $$ \limsup_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{|\varphi(B_{t,t+h})|}{\sqrt{h \ln\ln (1/h)}} \geq \lim_{n\uparrow \infty} \left|\varphi\left(\frac{B_{t,t+h_n}}{|B_{t,t+h_n)}|}\right)\right|\frac{|B_{t,t+h_n}|}{\sqrt{h_n \ln\ln (1/h_n)}} =\sqrt{2}.$$

But there is no guarantee that this will happen; in particular, there is no guarantee that the range of $\frac{B_{t,t+h}}{|B_{t,t+h}|}$ will even intersect the set $\{x_n\}$.

Comment: Is it the case that $B_{t,t+h}$ is notation for $B_{t+h}-B_t$? If so, the process $h\mapsto \phi(B_{t,t+h})$ is (for fixed $t$) a standard Brownian motion, to which the LIL can be applied.